# Adding header to row labels by kable function

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am trying to produce the following table in R markdown.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlOoB.jpg)

My attempt:

```
library(kableExtra)
rownames = c("Positive", "Negative")
colnames = c("Positive", "Negative")

d <- matrix(c("a","b","c","d"), 
            nrow=2, dimnames = list(rownames, colnames))

kable(d,longtable = T, booktabs = T, align="c") %>%
       add_header_above(c(" ", "True diagnosis" = 2))
```

How to add header to row labels as shown in the uploaded table picture and add vertical and horizontal lines?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use additional functions from the kableExtra package

```
library(kableExtra)
rownames = c("Positive", "Negative")
colnames = c("Positive", "Negative")

d <- matrix(c("a","b","c","d"), 
            nrow=2, dimnames = list(rownames, colnames))

kable(d,longtable = F, booktabs = F, align="c") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", "True diagnosis" = 2)) %>% 
  kable_styling() %>% 
  column_spec (1:3,border_left = T, border_right = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(kableExtra)
rownames = c("Screening test", "Screening test")
colnames = c("", "Positive", "Negative")

d <- matrix(c("Positive","Negative","a","b","c","d"), 
            nrow=2, dimnames = list(rownames, colnames))

kable(d,longtable = T, booktabs = T, align="c") %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 1) %>%
  column_spec (1,border_right = T, bold = T) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 2, "True diagnosis" = 2))
```

If that doesn't work straight away try updating your kableExtra with `install_github`:

```
devtools::install_github(repo="haozhu233/kableExtra", ref="a6af5c0")
```